# WPF Putting the values ​of the datagrid into the dataset

Tags: wpf

[WPF]
Putting the values ​​of the datagrid into the dataset.
[Window form code]

```
ds = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

[my source code]

`ds = (DataSet)datagrid.ItemsSource;`

[error]

> ds = (DataSet)datagrid.ItemsSource; <- exception error

Comment: Could you provide us more information like the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because the ItemsSource is not a DataSet.

It cannot be.

A WPF datagrid Itemssource can be bound or set to a number of things.

When thinking about things in the System.Data namespace, a datagrid itemssource will set/bind to the view of a datatable.

Notice, not the datatable directly.

If you have a datatable dt then that would be:

```
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

( You can optionally sort and filter in views ).

A dataset has one or more datatables in it.

If you just had a datatable you can new up a dataset and add your datatable to that:

```
  DataSet customers = new DataSet();  
  DataTable customersTable = customers.Tables.Add("CustomersTable");
```

Given a dataset you can pick out a datatable from that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter

```
 DataTable customersTable = customers.Tables["Customers"];
```